# How to trigger breakpoint in u-sql code behind (usql.cs) file?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-analysis-services

> The break point never trigger on submit job even i tried with local
>   account having all dll on my system.

Comment: the code behind execute and gives output but no break point trigger for inspection.

Comment: Please help....

Comment: Please post the code and script involved. Are you sure the code is even called by the U-sql script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug u-sql c# assemblies, you will need to select "Debug" build and start with F5 / Run.  If the break point is inside code behind file, it will be handled automatically.   If it is in external assemblies, you will need to make sure the correspondent symbol files (*.pdb) can be loaded automatically by VS debugger. You can, for example, either register these symbol files as "WITH ADDITIONAL FILES" during assembly registration, or to follow the guides here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017

You can always check the output log window to see if the correspondent symbols are loaded.

Alternatively, you can add this in the correspondent code to force a break. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks alot.
May i know how can I use Newtonsoft.Json in usql.cs file. We cannot add nuget package then how to use Newtonsoft???

Comment: Code behind is not meant to be used for complex assemblies that has external dependencies as these external assemblies will not be registered automatically when you use code behind.  In your case, I suggest that you create a separate C# assembly project that implements your function which can refer to nuget packages. However, for the query to work, you will also need to extract the Newtonsoft.Json assembly from the Nuget package (a renamed ZIP file) and then register and reference in your query.